# How to know when AWS SNS/SQS/Lambda have finished processing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a personal project that should process data once a day, I want to do the processing asynchronously in multiple threads. When it's finished I want to combine the result of all the processing into one single report. But I don't know how to detect when the processing is finished.

I want to do it as a learning project with AWS, I haven't used AWS at all this far. The plan is to use SQS and/or SNS to handle messages and lambdas to do the processing. One message can be consumed by multiple lambdas, and the lambdas can create new messages. The final report should also be created from a lambda.

The problem is to know when everything is finished (multiple threads/lambdas/messages have finished processing), and the report can be created. I really have no clue on how to do it.

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Publish a message to SNS/SQS from Lambda when you're done and subscribe to that to know when it's done.

Comment: @kichik I thought about that. But I don't understand how to get it to work with multiple threads/lambdas doing the processing. I can put a message on SNS/SQS for each of the finished processes, and receive multiple messages to the report creating lambda. But how would I know that all 5, 10, 100 or so processing have finished?

Comment: Step Functions could be a candidate if the workflow is non-trivial.

Comment: You can process a message in a single Lambda and create separate processing threads in the one Lambda and join up the results there.  It's certainly possible, though I'm not sure that would work for you project.

Comment: As @jarmod mentioned, this is a perfect use case for a Step Function.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a matter of waiting until the SQS queue has zero messages in the queue and zero message in-flight?

Comment: @jarmod I didn't know about step functions, will read up on it. Thanks.

Comment: @user212514 that seems like a possibility, but maybe not for this project. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that seems like a nice way of doing it. But I can't find out how to get the exact amount of messages. In the GetQueueAttributes API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html) there are responses of ApproximateNumberOfMessages in different states, but since it's only approximate I can't use the data. Are there another API that can be used? Or even better, is there a way to automatically trigger a lambda when the queues are empty?

Comment: If you know in advance the number of steps that need to complete then you could potentially solve this using an atomic counter in DynamoDB. Increment that atomic counter as each step completes and use DynamoDB Streams so that a Lambda function is called each time the counter is incremented. When the count reaches the expected number, trigger your complete processing. If it's not as simple as a single counter, say it's multiple counters or states, then you could do that similarly.

Comment: @Polygorial It is "approximate" due to the consistency model used by SQS. If you set an alarm to say zero messages for a period of 5 minutes, then it will definitely be completed. By the way, it's possible that zero messages won't actually trigger an alarm, so you might need to set it to trigger on `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` instead (since zero might not be a metric).